# ffmpeg zoompan image to video with original sizes

Tags: ffmpeg, video

How do I make `ffmpeg` use input image ratio/dimensions for output video file with `zoompan` filter applied? Input images can have arbitrary dimensions (1000x500, 4000x3500 etc.).

Example command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -filter_complex 'zoompan=z='\''min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)'\'':x='\''iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)'\'':y='\''ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)'\'':d=250,trim=duration=10' -y ouput.pm4
```

- there's an `:s` option for zoompan filter (from [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zoompan)), but it looks like I can't use a reference to the original input image size, only absolute (e.g. `:s=1000x800`)
- alternatively, there's an `-s` flag for ffmpeg command itself, but how to set the right dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413276/ffmpeg-zoom-over-a-squared-image), we have to check the input size manually.

We may use some programming for getting the resolution of the input, and adjust FFmpeg the command accordingly.
The best way I know is using a Python script.

I managed to create a Windows (non-optimal) batch file that gets the resolution using FFprobe, and store it into environment variable `INPUT_RES`:

Batch file example (for Windows):

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=s=x:p=0 input.jpg > log.txt
for /F "tokens=1* delims= " %%i in (log.txt) do set INPUT_RES=%%i
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -filter_complex "format=yuv444p,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015\,1.5)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=250:s=%INPUT_RES%,trim=duration=10" -y output.mp4
```

In Linux it supposed to be simpler, see: [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash).

---

In case you want the size to be proportional to the input, you may use `scale` filter.
It supposed be simple to scale `input.jpg` into a temporary image file (using FFmpeg scale filter), and get the resolution of the temporary image file.